# Atualizar pagina ao fechar um modal

Tags: php, javascript, html

como faço pra atualizar uma pagina sempre que o modal é fechado ?
pois estou com um problema de que sempre que eu fecho o modal e vou abrir novamente ele nao abre... sendo assim preciso atualizar a pagina ai ele abre.

modal usado

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modalInfoMaq" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modaleditcadastro">Informaçoes maquina:</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="AtualizarPagina()">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg" >
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Numero Serie</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serie_maquina" id="serie_maquina" readonly="readdonly">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg" >
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Modelo</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="grupo_maquina" id="grupo_maquina" readonly="readdonly">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div id="maquina_carrega" class="col-8 col-sm-6">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="maquina_carrega_rec" class="col-8 col-sm-6">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

e o script que envia os dados para o modal

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#btnInfoMaq", function () {
    var info = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var str = info.split('|');
    var serie_maquina = str[0];
    var grupo_maquina = str[1];
    $(".modal-body #serie_maquina").val(serie_maquina);
    $(".modal-body #grupo_maquina").val(grupo_maquina);
    console.log(serie_maquina);
    console.log(grupo_maquina);
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'info_maquina.php',
        data: {
            'serie':serie_maquina,
            'grupo':grupo_maquina
        },
        async:false,
        erro: function () {
            alert('erro');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#maquina_carrega").html(data);
            $("#maquina_carrega").html(data);
        }

    });
});
```

o problema e que quando eu abro ele uma vez... e fecho, quando tento abrir novamente ele abre e fecha. e depois nao faz mais nada.

Comment: Recarregar a página pode causar uma experiência ruim para o usuário, talvez fosse melhor identificar o motivo do modal não abrir novamente. Edite sua pergunta e inclua seu código para que possamos te auxiliar.

Comment: Consegue postar o código que você está usando? Basta você [editar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/291625/edit).

Comment: Editado!  se puderem me dar uma luz agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.location.href para capturar a página atual e window.location.href=URL para redirecionar para uma página.

Ex.:

```
var urlAtual = window.location.href;
window.location.href=urlAtual; // aqui vai fazer o redirecionamento
```

:)